# How to configure SSL Ciphers suite for mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ssl, nosql

I have a mongodb replica set instance with SSL enabled.

I am trying to configure SSL cipher suites for mongodb, but I didn't get any solution. Is it possible to configure cipher suite?

Answer (score 1):

according to [SERVER-6641](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6641?focusedCommentId=515467&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-515467), this isn't configurable:

> In [SERVER-10520](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10520) we made the decision to explicitly disallow all SSL ciphers that are considered weak. Specifically we only allow ciphers of strength HIGH and disallow EXP.

… however that seems to have [changed](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/b964786f0ce519caf214f4c321d2a2abf9580365) in [SERVER-29568](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29568).

according to the related Jira [DOCS-10445](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10445), [you should be able to set an OpenSSL cipher config like this](https://github.com/mongodb/docs/commit/25c9e95c821f54d8bbafdf1bc41813fc4180aa2b)

```
mongod --setParameter opensslCipherConfig=HIGH:!EXPORT:!aNULL@STRENGTH
```